# SQL trigger not syntactically correct?

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I am entirely new to SQL and am attempting to make my first trigger. For some reason no matter what I do I always get the Unnamed: Error. I have gone as far as to use the code generated directly by the IDE itself and it still won't run.
**This is run using MARIA DB**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pc_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `pc` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF pc.speed <= 0 THEN
        SET NEW.speed = ABS(pc.speed);
    END IF;
END
```

This is the code made by the IDE which I manually created the trigger with but it refuses to run (yes I deleted the trigger I created before running it)

```
CREATE TRIGGER pcSpeedProof
BEFORE INSERT
ON pc
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF pc.speed <= 0 THEN
        SET NEW.speed = ABS(pc.speed);
    END IF;
END
```

I have tried removing the begins, moving the ends, adding and removing the end if but it just refuses to work. Every time it is the same error **SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax ... to use near " at line #.** Depending on how I space it out the error line # is either where ON pc is it would say near " at line 7 or if I remove some enters its now near " at line 4 etc.

Just for full clarity here are all the tables being used:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    maker VARCHAR(255),
    model INT,
    type VARCHAR(255),

    PRIMARY KEY(model)
);

CREATE TABLE PC (
    model INT,
    speed DOUBLE,
    ram INT,
    hd INT,
    price INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(model) REFERENCES Product(model)
);

CREATE TABLE Laptop(
    model INT,
    speed DOUBLE,
    ram INT,
    hd INT,
    screen DOUBLE,
    price INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(model) REFERENCES Product(model)
);

CREATE TABLE Printer(
    model INT,
    color VARCHAR(255),
    type VARCHAR(255),
    price INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(model) REFERENCES Product(model)
);
```

What is syntactically incorrect for the triggers?

Comment: Remove the backticks and try again - does it fail then?

Comment: You should make all of your columns `NOT NULL` and you need to add `PRIMARY KEY` constraints to all of your tables. Also, your DB design is not normalized.

Comment: Regardless of the previous comments about the design of the data model (what you should check), the specific problem in creating the trigger is that a `DELIMITER` is missing, see [MariaDB :: Delimiters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/).